# Usage of Synergy

Tags: network-manager, ethernet

in using synergy is it a must that in the computers in network one is a server and the others clients or can work pick a server at random in a network with no sever and no clients specified and with all ping to one another.

Comment: Please see http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synergy for synergy. They have their own space on superuser.

Answer (score 2):

Eh, that is not what Synergy does. Basically it is a set of computers connected over a network that share 1 keyboard and 1 mouse.

Server in this case means the computer that has the keyboard and mouse. The clients means those systems that are connected to that (single) keyboard and (single) mouse.

So you need to actually sit in front of the main computer (ie. server) and have to see at least the displays for the connected computers (ie. clients) or at least some idea on how/where to move the mouse.